# Should I delete the mysql database user id created for my site by the developer?

Tags: mysql

I am a newbie when it comes to anything related to databases. I cut ties with my developer who had set up my site and was hosting it too about six months ago. I moved my site to a new host thinking that that was the end of that.

I realised recently that he also had access to the database as he'd created a privileged user id originally(a user by his name kept showing up in my sql processes). Can he still access my database on my new host or is this user showing only because it is the only default user?

I asked my hosting company if this was a concern but they said it was not an issue. I have my doubts though. Can anyone please tell me how to educate myself about this and if this is a concern. I just want to learn enough to be able to run my content based wordpress site.

Recently my site experienced a brute force attack so I want to take all precautionary measures when it comes to security.

If this is a concern will simply deleting this user from the cpanel take care of things?
Please help

Comment: Is your developer is accessing Database

Comment: I don't know. When i check my sql processes, user by the id name originally created by him does show but i don't know if that just means i have opened my own site since there is only one user created for the site(the one created by him)

Comment: I think it may be the same user is used in config file and browsing the application uses that credentials. You must change the password atleast or create a user and change the config file credentials

Comment: Thanks for responding. Is there a how to document for doing the same that u can recommend? Should i delete this user and create a new one?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the password in wordpress account as shown in 
[Resetting_Your_Password](http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password)

and change the cPanel user password also for secuirty concern.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the user that was configured in WP that happens to be the dev's name/id.

First try this to see what users are there:

`select user,host from mysql.user;`

I would still change the password for security. If WP instance and DB is on same host, limiting the access to `localhost` only minimizes chance for DB-related attack.

use `show grants for 'jeffrey'@'userhost_or_ip';`

and copy the grants and paste back, replacing host section with `localhost`:

ex)
`grant SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE on wp_35.* to jeffrey@localhost;`

Use `flush privileges` to refresh the ids, and drop any unused user. Also, make sure to reflect the change in WP config.